# how to create number looping in javascript with certain conditions

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have array var arrayObject as attribute_1 ([original], [Cool Mint], [Freshburst]) and each of them has three same attribute as attribute_2 ([250], [500], [750]).
[image: array on con]

I set var num to looping a number on field Product No, but the number that I want looks wrong, I want it to be sorted from 0 - 8 like 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8. What kind of conditions should I do for this?

```
var num = 0;
$.each(arrayObject, function(key,value) {
    var attr1Data = Object.keys(value)[0],
        attr2Data = Object.values(value)[0],
        i = 0;

    html += '<tr>';
        html += '<td rowspan="'+rowspan+'">'+attr1Data+'<input name="post[item]['+(key)+'][attribute1]" type="hidden" value="'+attr1Data+'" /></td>';
        html += '<td>'+attr2Data[i]+'<input name="post[item]['+(key)+'][attribute2][]" type="hidden" value="'+attr2Data[i]+'" /></td>'; 
        html += '<td><input class="pn" placeholder="..." name="post[item]['+(key)+'][product_no][]" type="text" value="'+num+'" /></td>';
        html += '<td><input class="as" size="4" name="post[item]['+(key)+'][actual_stock][]" type="text" value="0" /></td>';
        html += '<td><input class="p" size="7" name="post[item]['+(key)+'][price][]" type="text" value="0.00" /></td>';
    i++;
    html += '</tr>';
    while(i < rowspan) {

        html += '<tr>';
        html += '<td>'+attr2Data[i]+'<input name="post[item]['+(key)+'][attribute2][]" type="hidden" value="'+ attr2Data[i] +'" /></td>';
        html += '<td><input class="pn" placeholder="..." name="post[item]['+(key)+'][product_no][]" type="text" value="'+num+'" /></td>';
        html += '<td><input class="as" size="4" name="post[item]['+(key)+'][actual_stock][]" type="text" value="0" /></td>';
        html += '<td><input class="p" size="7" name="post[item]['+(key)+'][price][]" type="text" value="0.00" /></td>';
        html += '</tr>';
        i++;
    }
    num++;
})
```

[image: result]

Comment: you are resetting i everytime, define i outside foreach

Comment: i have edit my code and result

Comment: `value="'+(++num)+'"`

Comment: @ogebman please add code snippet so can give you proper answer